# Searching objects from c# list between date range - Performance Oriented

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am using the method below to find a list of objects (from a sharepoint list) between a date range using a LINQ query. It is working fine but takes a lot of time, can it be optimized?

```cs
public System.Collections.Generic.List<ItineraryModel> FilterDashboard(string StartDate, string EndDate ,ClientContext clientContext, SharePointContext spContext)
{

        var src = this.SpHelper.getAllListData(clientContext).ToList<ItineraryModel>();

        System.Collections.Generic.List<ItineraryModel> source2 = src.Where(delegate (ItineraryModel x)
        {                        
              if (!(System.Convert.ToDateTime(x.StartDate).Date > System.Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate).Date))
              {                          
                   return !(System.Convert.ToDateTime(x.EndDate).Date < System.Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate).Date);
              }
              return false;
         }).ToList<ItineraryModel>();

         return source2.Distinct<ItineraryModel>().ToList<ItineraryModel>();                
}
```

Comment: What you are doing --- fetching the whole list and applying filter over it. Is it possible to call the sharepoint with DateFilter so that API it self returns the filtered data. What is return type of `this.SpHelper.getAllListData(clientContext)`? - `IQueryable`? Suggestion - you don't need the `DateTime` conversion on `StartDate` and `EndDate` for every record. You can convert those two string dates to DateTime object before `Where` code statement. However, it will hardly make any performance improvement.

Comment: Does the database have the DateTime stored as a DateTime or string.  You are doing a lot of work converting to a DateTime from a string to a DateTime which may not be necessary.

Comment: What is being returned from the getAllListData function? Can you run diagnostics using a stopwatch class to see where exactly your slow down is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If src has 1000 elements, how many times will you convert StartDate from string to a DateTime. Wouldn't it be more efficient if you would only do this once?

Furthermore, you return a List. Are you sure that all your callers will need the complete list? Could it be that some callers only want to know whether there are any elements? of maybe they want only the first element, or do first 24 elements to display on a screen. In other words: wouldn't it be more efficient to return an IEnumerable instead of a List.

> If you create a LINQ like function, always consider to return an IEnumerable instead of a List, especially if you don't need the List to create your function.

Now you forgot to tell us the return value of GetAllListData.But let's assume that GetAllListData returns an IEnumerable sequence of ItenaryModels.

Apparently every ItenaryModel has at least a StartDate and an EndDate. You don't want all ItenaryModels, you only want those ItenaryModels that started in the interval of input parameters startDate and endDate, or in other words where property StartDate >= input parameter startDate and property EndDate <= input parameter endDate.

```
IEnumerable<ItenaryModel> FilterDashboard(string textStartDate, string textEndDate, ...)
{
    // TODO: check for non-null textStartDate, textEndDate
    // convert the input dates to DateTime:
    DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(textStartDate);
    DateTime endDate = Datetime.Parse(textEndDate);
    // TODO: decide what to do if dates can't be parsed
    // TODO: decide what to do if startDate > endDate?

    IEnumerable<ItenaryModel> itenaryModels = this.SpHelper.getAllListData(clientContext);

    // the easiest is a foreach, alternatively use a LINQ where.
    foreach (var itenaryModel in itenaryModels)
    {
        DateTime itenaryStartDate = DateTime.Parse(itenaryModel.StartDate.Date);
        DateTime itenaryEndDate = DateTime.Parse(itenaryMode.EndDate.Date);
        // TODO: decide what to do if can't be parsed

        if (startDate <= itenaryStartDate && itenaryEndDate <= endDate)
        {
             // put this itenaryModel in the returned enumeration
             yield return itenaryModel;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use a LINQ where. This is not faster!

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(textStartDate);
DateTime endDate = Datetime.Parse(textEndDate);
IEnumerable<ItenaryModel> itenaryModels = this.SpHelper.getAllListData(clientContext);

return itenaryModels.Where(itenaryModel =>
           startDate <= DateTime.Parse(itenaryModel.StartDate.Date) &&
           DateTime.Parse(itenaryModel.EndDate.Date) <= endDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the list items into the memory as a whole, then search for it. @Harald Coppoolse has given all possible answers about LINQ.

As an alternative approach, you can utilize CAML queries for that. You are using `SPHelper` whose internals are alien to me. But you can use old school SharePoint CAML queries for performance.